# App Id and Secret key Facebook for Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, app-id

I'm creating a facebook application on the Android platform ... to make a thesis ... I was wondering ... but because we need to create an application on facebook?
What is the App ID and Secret Key?

The digital signature serves to recognize the developer ... but app_id and the secret key  I do not understand what they are ...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I told you it wouldn't be a secret! No I'm just kidding. The API key and secret key are generated when you create a new application.

Answer (score 0):

click on the developer link at the bottom of your facebook page

at the top of the developer page click on the api link

on the right side of the api page there is a button "create app" click on it and fill in the forms and when done you'll get an appid and secret key